# Wix bundle - how to upgrade only one MSI package

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn

I have one Wix bundle that contains two MSI's. I want to upgrade only one of the MSI's, so I have increased the version of my bundle and the version of the desired MSI.

During the upgrade, the MSI that was already installed with the same version keeps getting uninstalled no matter what.

I get always this log :

```
Plan disabled rollback for package: First.msi, due to incomplete cache: None, original rollback action: Install
```

And after that

```
Planned package: First.msi, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: Uninstall, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Unregister
```

Comment: Is this a major upgrade? This would require a change of product IDs. Would you like to to show all changes in the .wxs files you've done?

Comment: Yes, is a major update. I have changed the the product ID for the second MSI. The first MSI is the same as the first version of te bundle, no changes on first msi were made.